# Sealing gap(s) around cabinet pipe penetrations

Tags: kitchens, sink

I own a slab house. Under the kitchen sink there are gaps around the pipes on the base of the cabinet, a good 1/2 inch gap. I'm wondering if I can seal those gaps and what the best method would be. I am smelling an odd odor that I can't put my finger on and suspect it might be coming from the gaps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because oder identification is specifically off topic per the help center.

Comment: I reworded the question to (hopefully) align with question format requirements.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm wondering if I can seal those gaps if that might eliminate the odor?

Well, yes, if the odor is coming through the gaps. You could try to stuff something like fabric or cotton in there as a temporary seal, and seeing if it reduces the smell.

I think it would be easier to solve your issue if you could definitively identify the source of the smell first. It could be coming from your garbage disposal, mold on walls, the trash bin, or other things.

Comment: Agreed, fine answer. Some of the "other things" might be unpleasant but important to find, like a broken drain pipe under the slab, a rancid festering spill, or a dead animal.